# Pyspark : How to transform dataframe without the caracter

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

| Matricule (type array) |
| --- |
| [TKI1] |
| [TKI4] |

I will obtain this dataframe

| Matricule (type string) |
| --- |
| TKI1 |
| TKI4 |

Comment: What have you been trying so far?

Comment: You do aware that array might hold more than one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Marticule` is of `ArrayType` in the beginning. You can directly utilise [getItem](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html) as below -

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Matricule':[['TKI1'],['TKI4']],
})

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+---------+
|Matricule|
+---------+
|   [TKI1]|
|   [TKI4]|
+---------+

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- Matricule: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

#### Get Item

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('Matricule_string',F.col('Matricule').getItem(0))

sparkDF.show()

+---------+----------------+
|Matricule|Matricule_string|
+---------+----------------+
|   [TKI1]|            TKI1|
|   [TKI4]|            TKI4|
+---------+----------------+
```